# Apache Ignite; failed to connect cluster, connection failed

Tags: java, mysql, docker, ignite

I'm trying to use ApacheIgnite to make SQL queries.

Basically I can't connect to my port, which is in execution in docker IP:172.17.0.1 and my SQL port: 3606

POM configurations are the following:

```
Ignite-core:2.7.6
ignite-indexing: 2.7.6
mysql-connector-java: 8.0.17
```

```
    private static Connection igniteConnection;
    private static Statement sql;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

        IgniteConfiguration conf = new IgniteConfiguration();
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(conf);

        igniteConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost:3606/test;user=root;password=root");

        sql = igniteConnection.createStatement();

        sql.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Employee (" +
        " id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30), country VARCHAR(30))");

        PreparedStatement sql = igniteConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Employee (id, name, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

        sql.setLong(1, 1);
        sql.setString(2, "James");
        sql.setString(3, "EEUU");
        sql.executeUpdate();

        rs = sql.executeQuery("SELECT e.name, e.country FROM Employee");

        while(rs.next()){
            String name = rs.getString(1);
            String country = rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(name+"\t"+country);
        }

        ignite.close();
        igniteConnection.close();
        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **10800** to connect

By default, Ignite uses the following local ports:
**10800** Default port for thin client connection

**11211** Default JDBC port

**47100** Default local communication port

**47500** Default local discovery port

**8080** Default port for REST API

**49128** Default port for JMX connection

**31100~31200** Default time server port

**48100~48200** Default shared memory port

Comment: I tried what you recommended meand  I even modified docker yet I got this error: Failed to connect to Ignite cluster

Answer (score 0):

`3606` is MySQL port if I'm not mistaken. Apache Ignite would use `10800` for SQL port by default. Please try that one after making sure it is exported out of Docker.

Comment: I think that I tried every possible port in Docker and in MAIN too, and everytime I got the same error:
* Failed to connect to Ignite cluster.
* Failed to connect to server.
Nevertheless thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, some of them should definitely work. I bet you didn't patch it through.